# @BeforeClass method execution in TestNG during inheritence

Tags: java, testng

I have just started using TestNG, and I had a question in mind. If class `A` has a `@BeforeSuite` method and class `B` is inheriting class `A` like in the below example:

class A file:

```
class A
{
  @BeforeSuite
  public void beforeTest()
  {
    //something
  }
}
```

class B file:

```
class B extends A
{
 @Test
 public void executeTest()
 {
  //something
 }
}
```

So, in this scenario, the `@BeforeSuite` from class `A` will run for sure when I try and execute `ClassB:executeTest()`. Is there any way I could disable the `@BeforeSuite` method from running, without excluding the inheritance or disabling the `@Test` method?

Comment: Why not run the test and update your question accordingly?

Comment: The reason is I really can't. If I could do the trial and error I would have. And unfortunately I did not find any related posts on the same. So, thought of asking the stackoverflow community in the hope someone does know about this.

Comment: @SumitRoy Why do you want to prevent the `@BeforeSuite` method from the class A, which is most likely needed by the class A to work? Please edit your question to include the specific problem you try to solve, maybe you need to approach it in a different way (see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @SumitRoy please check my answer below. It allows you to disable `BeforeSuite` method without excluding the inheritance. If it satisfies you, then please mark it as accepted or useful. We all here spending some time to answer questions and deserve at least minimal reward. Between, I don't think that there is any nicer solution regarding your question. Regards.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I think your solution is a viable one. I will accept your answer. Apologies for the late reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override method like in example below. `@BeforeSuite`of the base class will not be executed in this case.

TestA:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.log4testng.Logger;

public class TestA {
    protected static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TestA.class);

    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        LOGGER.warn("beforeSuite - TestA");
    }
}
```

TestB:

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestB extends TestA {

    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        LOGGER.warn("beforeSuite - TestB");
    }

    @Test
    public void executeTest() {
        LOGGER.warn("executeTest - TestB");
    }
}
```

Run TestB and check output:

```
[TestA] [WARN] beforeSuite - TestB
[TestA] [WARN] executeTest - TestB

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```